# Add a dotted vertical line on certain x-axis values using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The axis values are -6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6 with some y values in a density plot.

Is it possible to *add dotted vertical lines* on certain x-axis values (Forex: -3 and +3 )using ggplot?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000, 0, 1), y = rnorm(1000,
     0, 2), z = rnorm(1000, 2, 1.5))
df.m <- melt(df)
ggplot(df.m) + geom_freqpoly(aes(x = value,
     y = ..density.., colour = variable))
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Try `geom_vline`:

```
ggplot(df.m) +
  geom_freqpoly(aes(x=value, y=..density.., colour=variable)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(-3,3), linetype="dotted")
```

[image: geom_vline example]

Comment: this answer is so simplistic

Comment: and with long dash's `geom_vline(xintercept=c(-3, 3), linetype = "longdash")`