# Change grid line behavior in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have the following data:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(x = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE))
```

I want to create a dot plot of `data$x`, so this is what I do:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 20, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)
```

Which gives me this:

[image: dotplot1]

I would like to get rid of those vertical grid lines, so I add `theme(line = element_blank())` to my ggplot statement. The problem is that command also eliminates the tick marks, which I would like to keep. **How can I hide the grid lines whilst keeping their respective ticks**?

I would also like to know how I can change the grid lines so they'll be drawn every `1:20`, not at every 0.5 mark.

I've looked for those answers in `?title()` and `?geom_dotplot`, tried a couple of things, to no avail. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `panel.grid`

```
theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

If you want the grid lines to be drawn every 1:20, not at every 0.5 mark.

```
 theme(panel.grid.minor =   element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major =   element_line(colour = "white",size=0.75))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, all those theme options made me miss this. ;)

Comment: Any takes on my subquestion, on changing the grid marks to `1:20`?

Answer (score 3):

you might find answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465233/theme-manipulation-in-ggplot2-altering-x-and-y-grid-lines)

`opts` has been changed to `theme`. but the thing about grid.major.x, grid.minor.y should set on the track

To get rid of the major grid line, for example

```
ggplot(data, aes(x)) +
    geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 20, 1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```