# How can I use my PCA scores in a graph that wills show scores per order on a fixed horizontal line?

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to recreate a graph from a paper with my own data. 
This graph will illustrate where my species lie on a arbitrate continuum (slow to fast). I mostly work with R, but I have also tried in Excel.

My question is, how can I use my Principal Component Analysis (first axes) scores in a graph that wills show scores per order on a fixed horizontal line, but show the PCA scores as dots on the horizontal line. The longer the line, the more scores this order has.
[This is the graph I'm trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C17QY.png)

Say order Lagomorpha has scores (-0.61339985, -0.42000761)
and order Artiodactyla has  (1.15392095, -0.61332118, -0.29332786, 0.15553337, 0.15605178, -0.19583598, 0.0603664, -0.4795726, -0.90818082)

Comment: This seemed like a similair question, but unfortunatley was not was I was looking for

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718871/add-a-dotted-vertical-line-on-certain-x-axis-values-using-ggplot

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432488/horizontal-line-graph-with-assambly-in-r